# Sending an image via Bluetooth from android to a pc

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have just starded to work with Android and I have to create an app that takes a picture and then sends it to a pc via bluetooth.
The problem is when I have to send the image, because I can't find a simply code to do this.
I can have everytime the uri of the picture I took before, so i need a code that searches for the active devices near mine and then sends the picture to the one of them I choose.
Please help me!
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For discovering nearby bluetooth devices, you can refer following links which will help you to understand it better:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#FindingDevices
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#DiscoveringDevices

And if you want to Enable device bluetooth without asking the user. You can  use this in your manifest file.

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand BluetoothServerSocket Programming in android.

http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.bluetooth.BluetoothServerSocket

Follow this link ... Hope this will help you.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html

Follow this link to understand bluetooth in android.